# Does passing data from the child to the parent effect performance? (ReactJs)

Tags: reactjs, cart

I am working on an online shop for a client, and I need to pass data between the child and the parent to update the cart. Everything is working fine, I'm just wondering if this effects performance. Is there any way around this? Here is a mock example of what I've done:

```
const Parent = () => {
    const [cart, setCart] = useState([])
    
    function changeCart(newCart){
        setCart(newCart)
    }
    return(
        <Child cartFunction = {changeCart} cart = {cart}/>
    )
}
const Child = (props) => {
    const [cart, setCart] = useState(props.cart)
    
    function changeCart(newcart){
        setCart(newcart)
        props.cartFunction(cart)
    }
    return(
        <button onClick = {() => changeCart(["Apples", "Oranges"])>Add Fruit</button>
    )
}
```

Is there anything wrong with this system?

Answer (score 0):

Two thoughts:

- Does your child component need to keep its own state? (which is a duplication of the parent cart state)
- The function `changeCart` is unnecessary, you can pass a `setCart` instead, or change everything to `useReducer` as an option

Comment: yes, I just noticed that changeCart could be done completely inline. I made a duplication of the parent state, so that I would not have to keep checking the parent state multiple times, but just once. Does it make a difference? And in general, does this method reduce preformance?

Comment: By deleting the duplication you'll get rid of the redundant re-rendering and additional watchers. The only thing you need in this case is: `const [cart, setCart] = useState([])` in the parent component

Comment: Ah ok. So by directly accessing the parent component I prevent the re-renders. Got it. Thank you, and happy new year.